# Cross-compiling Makefile: dealing with test programs

Tags: iphone, gcc, makefile, cross-compiling, configure

I'm trying to cross-compile several libraries from OSX to iOS. I've successfully cross-compiled libjpeg and libogg.

But I can't compile libvorbis because `configure` insists on creating and running a small test program. This obviously fails, because it creates an `armv7` binary, fails to run it, and then interprets this as missing ogg libraries.

How do you usually deal with this kind of problem? I'm tempted to hack the configure script to work around these issues, but because of this kind of failure some features may be disabled. I'm also thinking of letting `configure` generate a native Makefile and then convert it to use the iOS toolchain, but this seems too error prone.

Any advice?

Comment: checking for oggpackB_read... no
configure: error: newer libogg version (1.1 or later) required

Comment: config.log says

ld: warning: directory '${exec_prefix}/lib' following -L not found
ld: warning: in /usr/local/lib/libogg.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)

It's trying to link with /usr/local/lib instead of /usr/local/ios/lib, although AFAIK I have every flag correctly set :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I tricked `configure` by explicitly making it link with ogg (`LDFLAGS="/usr/local/ios/lib/libogg-armv7.a" ./configure ...`) and then removed the explicit reference to the library from the generated makefile.

Comment: three things: first, you are abusing LDFLAGS to append to your link line (i.e. specifying the full path is not really a LD flag). The more correct thing would be LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/ios/lib". Second, your solution is just a more specific (i.e. will break as soon as you try and build something else) case of what I suggested. I.e. /usr/local/ios is your target root that I mentioned. And third, if the info was useful to you but wasn't a sufficient answer, you might consider voting up my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @kanaka, thanks for your comments; I've just upvoted your answer. As for the problem itself, passing -L was one of the first things I tried, but it didn't have any effect - configure kept trying to link to the system-wide ogg (maybe because a dylib has precedence over a static lib, I have no idea). I know it's a hack, but of all the libraries I had to cross-compile, this one was the only that had problems, and I had no intention or time to dig into configure internals.

Comment: yep, that's reasonable. autoconf (and especially libtool) can be fairly opaque in how the handle library path resolution. If you expect to build additional libraries and or applications with more than trivial dependencies you'll probably want to track the problem down. If it's just a one-off then do whatever works.

Answer (score 3):

If you are cross-compiling anything that has more dependencies than libc (glibc) it becomes much more complicated. You need to have already cross-compiled all the dependencies. And the cross-compiler toolchain and all helper build programs and scripts need to know how to find those dependencies (the cross-compiled libraries and headers).

You need to have already cross-compiled libogg (and its dependencies) and installed them into the cross-compile root directory. The headers and libraries from your build system can't be used for the host (arm7) system. They must be kept separate.

Also, if you want to have shared object libraries (*.so) and not just static libraries then there is a whole new set of complications. For example, while a cross-compiler toolchain contains a cross-compiled libc as part of the toolchain, you still need a libc for the host system. The libc that is part of the toolchain can be used for this, but the way it is structured is different than on the host system. Sometimes people copy and re-arrange the files, but often people just compile and install a new glibc for the root.

Anyways, all that to say, the two errors you are seeing are because the configure script is not able to find a cross-compiled libogg library. If you haven't already, you need to cross-compile libogg (and dependencies) and install them into your target root. Then you need to tell the configure script where your cross-compiled headers (yes, header are architecture specific) and libraries are in your target root. Usually using CFLAGS, LDFLAGS, CXXFLAGS, etc (NOT --prefix) but there may be other environment variables you need to set also to affect things like pkg-config, etc. After you have built each dependency, then you need to get the makefile to install the dependency to the root. Usually this is done with `make DESTDIR=[root] install` but some makefiles have their own mechanism (or no proper alternate install mechanism).

You may also need to override certain configure checks (using environment variables) that are poorly written and don't have good cross-compile defaults. These variables usually start with ac_cv_*

So the basic process is to do this for packages that you need (in dependency order):

```
export CFLAGS=-I[root]/usr/include LDFLAGS=-L[root]/usr/lib CXXFLAGS=-I[root]/usr/include
export ac_cv_[test1]=[yes|no] ac_cv_[test2]=[yes|no] ...
./configure --host=[arm7-blah-blah]
make
make DESTDIR=[root] install
```

Good luck. Once you feel comfortable with standard cross-compiling, then you will be ready to take on the real black art, the [Canadian cross](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler#Canadian_Cross) ;-)

Comment: Thanks for all the info :) In fact for a long time I used to cross-compile Windows binaries from Linux using the mingw environment, but I had never run into this problem.